# Accessing php.ini file

Tags: php, pear

I have problem a problem in making a php file run because of the error

```
Cannot redeclare _pear_call_destructors() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR.php on line 777
```

After investigation i found that only way make it run is to make changes in PHP settings

include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"   to

include_path = "."

But i am unable to find this

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

in my php.ini file. Which other files might i find this path?

Comment: "is to PHP settings" ? is to do what with the settings ? why do you have double include_path declarations ? bad copy&paste ? And what does a include_path could have to do with a "redeclaration" error anyway ? If it was not found ok, but it's already declared... Could you show some code please ?

Comment: I wouldnt change it in the php.ini... if its specific to this project then just change it as one of the first calls made with `set_include_path('.');`. That said the problem isnt an issue with the include path, its that youre trying to include the definition of a function twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the top of my head there are three ways you can set the include path in a script, to access this setting, in php.ini do a search for `include_path`.  *Make sure you target the proper .ini file!* Some setups have multiple .ini's. `phpinfo()` is your friend to identify the proper .ini location. If you have access to shell, easily grab all your ini info with:

```
 php -i | grep ini
```

If this .ini config change is not working out for some reason, you can try using [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) or [ini_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) functions at the top of your script to redeclare your include path. Here is an example partly ripped from php.net:

```
// Works as of PHP 4.3.0
set_include_path('.');

// Works in all PHP versions
ini_set('include_path', '.');
```

Good-luck, happy coding.

PS: If you are using custom pear packages that you downloaded,  either remove pear package from your OS with package-manager *or* override include_path with `set_include_path` or `ini_set` to prevent the pear that came with your distro from loading.

Comment: Thanxss a lot ..u made my day :):)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting it in your PHP script:

```
set_include_path('.');
```

Make sure this is at the *beginning* of your script, though. Also, if you need to add more stuff to the include path then this is your syntax:

```
set_include_path('/path/to/stuff' .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/something-else/' .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . '.'
);
```

Keep in mind, that was just an arbitrary example. For more info, visit [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).